# Which would be the best pricing?

Tags: editions

We have our Internal IT sales team who wants to setup their sales process in salesforce CRm.

Requirement:

- Basic CRM which can handle Raw data in database.
- Complete Sales flow Customization and Configuration.
- Admin Roles & user management. All type of security control configuration.
- Outlook Integration to track all their Meetings tasks notification in salesforce itself.

What will be the most reasonable pricing? We will have 5-7 users.

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask a sales representative of Salesforce directly. I'm voting to close this as 'too broad' because an answer that would help other people with similar questions (but different requirements) would be extremely long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go [here](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/), read about the features of various versions, then make a decision. The most important thing to consider is *features.* Select the smallest edition that will allow you to do everything you want to do. It's easy to upgrade, but not-easy to downgrade, so you might want to start with the Starter version, try it out, then upgrade when you run into a feature you need that you don't have.